# Do my azure account permissions affect my Virtual Machine operation

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Virtual Machine in azure that is set to boot up daily, run some scripts via cron, and then shut down.

A week ago my colleague changed my took away my co-adminstrator role within Azure. Since then the scripts have failed to run. I don't even know if the VM has been booting up.

How does the role/permissions associated with my account affect the behaviour of a VM that I have created?

EDIT

I suspect the point of failure is the Automation Task that starts the VM each day.

Comment: Are you running the scripts through azure automation? and what other permissions you have for your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does the role/permissions associated with my account affect the
> behaviour of a VM that I have created?

To run the automation tasks in a VM, the account which used to authenticate the VM should have the proper role/permissions.

As you are no longer the co-administrator of that Azure Subscription, you should have a proper role to run the automation tasks in a VM with your account.

For example, with the contributor role, you can create and run the automation tasks in your Azure VM